# How to query Azure DevOps Work Items using client_id and client_secret

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, microsoft-entra-id

I want to query Work Items through the Azure DevOps REST API. This is working when I'm using my PAT with work_write access.

Now I want to to the same using an application that should to this.

The steps I did:

1. Create a new application in Microsoft Entra through the Azure portal
2. Gave vso.work_write permission to that application and granted admin consent (although admin consent should not be needed)
3. Created a client_secret
4. Added that application as a user in Azure Devops and added assigned it the "Project Contributor" role to the project that I want to query.

I'm using the below PowerShell code to sign in and query the Work Items.
I can successfully sign in and I'm getting an access_token that looks just fine.
However the response to the WIQL query is the HTML of the sign in page.
I tested the same query using a PAT I created from my account using the same work_write permission and it worked just fine.

```
# Define the variables
$organization = "..."
$project = "..."
$clientId = "..."
$tenantId = "..."
$clientSecret = "..."
$baseurl = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project"
$tokenurl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/token"

# Get the access token
$body = @{
    client_id = $clientId
    client_secret = $clientSecret
    grant_type = "client_credentials"
    scope = "https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/vso.work_write"
}
$tokenresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $tokenurl -Method Post -Body $body -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
$token = $tokenresponse.access_token
echo $tokenresponse # This looks fine

# Define the WIQL query
$wiql = @{
    query = "SELECT [System.Id], [System.AssignedTo], [System.State], [System.Title] FROM workitems WHERE [System.TeamProject] = '$project' AND [System.State] = 'Resolved' AND [System.ChangedDate] < @today-7 AND [System.Tags] NOT CONTAINS 'Stale'"
} | ConvertTo-Json

# Post the WIQL query to the REST API
$wiqlurl = "$baseurl/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=7.1"
$wiqlresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $wiqlurl -Method Post -Body $wiql -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Bearer {0}" -f $token)}

echo $wiqlresponse # This is the html of the sign in page
```

What do I need to change in order to successfully execute the query?

Comment: delegated or application permissions in the app registration?

Comment: When I ran your script in my environment, I too got [html page for sign in](https://i.imgur.com/4g2uNsA.png) as response.  You need to change your scope to `499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default` to resolve error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To resolve the error, you need to change **scope** value to **`499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default`** and use **v2.0** token URL in your PowerShell script.

In my case, I registered one Azure AD application and added it as **user** in Azure DevOps- organization with "Project Contributor" role:

[image]

Now, I ran below **modified** script by changing values of `$scope` and `$tokenurl` parameters like this:

```
# Define the variables
$organization = "sridevOpsdemo"
$project = "sriproj1"
$clientId = "appId"
$tenantId = "tenantId"
$clientSecret = "secret"
$baseurl = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project"
$tokenurl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token"

# Get the access token
$body = @{
    client_id = $clientId
    client_secret = $clientSecret
    grant_type = "client_credentials"
    scope = "499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default"
}
$tokenresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $tokenurl -Method Post -Body $body -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
$token = $tokenresponse.access_token
echo $tokenresponse

$wiql = @{
    query = "Select [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.State] From WorkItems Where [System.WorkItemType] = 'Task' order by [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority] asc, [System.CreatedDate] desc"
} | ConvertTo-Json

$wiqlurl = "$baseurl/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=7.1"
$wiqlresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $wiqlurl -Method Post -Body $wiql -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Bearer {0}" -f $token)}
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I echoed **`$wiqlresponse`**, I got **response** with work items details successfully like below:

```
 echo $wiqlresponse
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[Use service principals & managed identities - Azure DevOps | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/service-principal-managed-identity?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fmarketplace-extensibility%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops#q-can-i-use-a-service-principal-or-managed-identity-with-azure-cli)