how to generate a bearer token for Azure api, with microsoft api
I already managed to get a bearer token with Az cli, but I would like to find another way. I got a bearer token with a request POST to microsoft oauth2 api, but this token doesn't work.
At first, I tried the following request on postman :

Then, I got this token from the request :

I passed this token in the Authorization header for the request : https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=7.0.
The request doest work, with error 401 Unauthorized, and with the message "TF401444: Please sign-in at least once as xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx\xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx\xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx in a web browser to enable access to the service."

Initially, I too got same error when I ran Azure DevOps API call using token generated with wrong resource value like this:
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=7.0

Response:

To resolve the error, you need to change  resource  value to  499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798
In my case, I registered one Azure AD application and added it as  user  in Azure DevOps organization like this:

Now, I generated access token with resource value as 499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798 via Postman as below:
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id:appId
client_secret:secret
resource:499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798

Response:

When I used above token to call Azure DevOps REST API, I got the response successfully with project details as below:
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=7.0

Response:


where did you get the resource value? I tried with yours and it doesnt work

Have you added that Azure app registration as user in your Azure DevOps organization? 499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798 is resource value to generate token for Azure DevOps . Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77523451/how-to-query-azure-devops-work-items-using-client-id-and-client-secret/77524330#77524330

I dont have access to the app registration in my company... I only got the tenantId, secret... that I needed. The app is created but might not be a user. How do you add it as user?

You can add service principal too by clicking Add users option in Azure DevOps portal like this https://i.imgur.com/metCGBN.png. Enter your app registration name and add it like this https://i.imgur.com/nW7jH5G.png

With this method, the request has the permissions of the app/user we created? Is there a way to get a bearer token that works with the permissions of the user who ask it?

Yes, you need to switch to delegated flow for generating token with permissions of user. Please post new question with more details and share that link here
